# Once more: adjusting div to another divs height (dynamically)?

Tags: html, css, height

So here is a question once again about adjusting divs height to another. I found a lot of questions and answers for this, but can't seem to make it work. Therefore I am asking this once again.

The problem: 
I have 2 divs and their heights differ. I'd like to have the height of div X adjusted to the heighest (other) div. I'd like that to happen without javascript, since I'd like it to be compatible with resizing my browser screen and I don't want to need to use the resize function all the time to detect the screen size (hope that makes sense).

So here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/frLt1vmn/

```
<style>
#container2 {
margin: 10px auto;
width: 927px;
}
#leftCol2{  float: left;
    width: 195px;
    background: #FCF;
    z-index:-1;
    padding:0;
     margin:0;
    }
#rightCol2{float:right;
width:732px;
background: #CFF;
    z-index:1;
    padding:0;
     margin:0;
}
</style>
<div id="container2">
<div id="rightCol2">
How to adjust the divs automatically to the height of the other.
</div>
<div id="leftCol2">
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for helping out!

**EDIT**
I call the rightCol2 div first because of responsiveness. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/azL9uefv/

Comment: If they're stacked vertically then...you need JavaScript (tracking resize events). Is it such bad?!?!

Comment: Depending on your cross browser needs, flexbox might be a viable solution.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti; well ive been told that using that resizing event causes for the javascript to run a lot of times (everytime someone resizes the screen right?)

@SecondRikudo: how to use the flexbox to adjust heights then? Its compatible with IE 10 and higher right?

Comment: Yes it does (fire each time user resize windows, multiple times during resizing). Is it bad thing? Will you note any performance degradation for that? Well, probably not (you'd better try before you pick any other over-complicated solution to avoid this). That said you can _defer_ any operation until resizing is paused for few milliseconds but again...try, do you think 2 ms code execution will be ever noted?

Comment: Hi, how to do that.. i need the height to be adjusted when the screen is bigger than 1024px.. and, if resized under 1024px, i need the height to go away... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See my Fiddle for solution http://jsfiddle.net/frontDev111/sm6xqqyw/

I have done some changes in HTML and CSS.

You need to use `display:table` for parent container and `display:table-cell` for child containers.

Let me know if you have trouble with this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out: is it possible though to keep the divs order (and float them?) I need that to keep my layout responsive.

Comment: Which style you want to get in responsiveness? Describe the design and I'll try to get that

Comment: Hi, thanks. So I put the 'rightCol2' before the 'leftCol2' and float them, because when resizing to a screensize of <1024 I'd like them to be width 100% and first present the 'rightCol2' and below that the 'leftCol2'...See here: http://jsfiddle.net/azL9uefv/

Comment: See Separate fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/5rd9xwsc/2/ . You should use this code in @media for < 1024px

Comment: Hi, thank you. Tried that but I'd like to make it work for IE 9 at least.. any possibility for that? Thank you so much!

Comment: check this example please, hope this will help! http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-solving-the-equal-height-column-conundrum--cms-20403

Answer (score 0):

If you want do this only with css. You have to display div as **table**

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/frLt1vmn/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="container2">
<div id="leftCol2">
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
<p>In this example this div is heigher.</p>
</div>
    <div id="rightCol2">
How to adjust the divs automatically to the height of the other.
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container2 {
margin: 10px auto;
width: 927px;
    display: table;
}
#leftCol2{
    width: 195px;
    background: #FCF;
    z-index:-1;
    padding:0;
     margin:0;
    display: table-cell;
    }
#rightCol2{
width:732px;
background: #CFF;
    z-index:1;
    display: table-cell;
    padding:0;
     margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out: is it possible though to keep the divs order (and float them?) I need that to keep my layout responsive.

Comment: Let's try this method [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frLt1vmn/2/). Let me know it works.